# Xubuntu 20.04 Extend Screens not working

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have installed Xubuntu 20.04 in place of 18.03.  Extended screens (dual monitors worked fine in 18.03)
Display manager is set to autodetect screens but doesn't - only the initial screen from boot. Images are visible in both monitors but with the same image; there is no option to extend.
I installed arandr (advised from another post) and this fails with

(arandr:2055): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 15:39:41.515: gdk_atom_intern: assertion 'atom_name != NULL' failed
Help appreciated.

[Display panel showing one screen when 2 are attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQEA5.png)
[Advanced panel showing settings to detect monitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLSoo.png)